How to use contentRef of react-modal to change the position of modal?
My modal height can change as content is dynamic and the card above i want to show a modal also changes his position,I want my modal end exactly above that card

The title of the question seems Ok, but the description lacks detail and is difficult to read. I'd suggest adding code samples
